# Evaluate this integral containing a piecewise function.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, solution-verification

Please see the image for the problem. I am unfamiliar with integrating piecewise functions correctly, so I would like verification for this problem. **Did I get the correct answer?**

[image]

Comment: I did not check the calculation, but the idea is correct.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.